# Cannot run Edge on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

On Windows 10, I cannot find Edge anywhere and the icon does not exist on the taskbar.

I found an executable in:

```
C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

But when I try to run it, it crashes. Debugging, the exception is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDCF341276 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in MicrosoftEdge.exe: Fatal program exit requested.
```

Note: I'm local administrator on my machine.

Any suggestion to make it run properly?

Comment: Did you try the Internet Explorer icon? In my Windows 10, the Edge starts when I click on the IE icon ... .

Comment: My taskbar is empty... I only have the window-shaped start button.