# Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Trial

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I installed Windows 10 trial in one virtual machine to test my website in Edge.

But Edge is not starting, and there is no error (no warning, no message), just it: not starting...

I saw some similar questions, but without answer...

[Cannot run Edge on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1012146/cannot-run-edge-on-windows-10)

[how to install missing Microsoft Edge on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1177480/how-to-install-missing-microsoft-edge-on-windows-10)

Is it possible to fix ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate for us a bit more?  When you say that Edge isn't starting, what happens?  What do you see... an error message, or nothing at all?

Comment: nothing happens, no error, no freezing, no start...

Comment: Just to double-check, are you utilizing the built-in `Administrator` account on that Windows 10 machine or another account that you created/named yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Because you probably have the Win10 Enterprise LTSB (Long Term Servicing Branch), and Edge doesn't work on it.

http://www.techradar.com/news/software/microsoft-edge-s-enterprise-absence-may-lead-to-windows-10-fragmentation-1296280

http://www.zdnet.com/article/some-windows-10-enterprise-users-wont-get-microsofts-edge-browser/

Comment: I have Edge in Enterprise: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Judqr.png You mean Enterprise LTSB (long time version)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read this article:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33703.difference-between-ltsb-cb-cbb-for-windows-10.aspx

> 1. LTSB (Long Term Servicing Branch) - Programs like Edge, Cortana, Store, Outlook Mail. Outlook Calendar, OneNote, Weather, News, Sports, Money, Photos, Camera, Music, and Clock. and the Store are not available.
> 2. CB (Current Branch) – This is the latest version of Windows and is called Current Branch, this version receives all upgrades (new versions) and updates (patches) from Microsoft within a few days of their release.
> 3. CBB (Current Branch for Business) -  Current Branch For Business is NOT and edition or version of Windows 10, instead it is a SETTING in Windows 10.  You have enable DEFER UPGRADES in Windows Update settings.